# How do I make sure the like button stays liked after refresh?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a like button similar to Facebook but I'm currently facing some issues. After a user likes a post, the like button will turn blue. However, when they refresh the page, the like button will return to its default color (gray).

This is the HTML for the like button.

```js
function ajax_send(data, element) {

  var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

  ajax.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {

    if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {

      response(ajax.responseText, element);
    }

  });

  data = JSON.stringify(data);

  ajax.open("post", "<?=ROOT?>ajax.php", true);
  ajax.send(data);

}

function response(result, element) {

  if (result != "") {

    var obj = JSON.parse(result);
    if (typeof obj.action != 'undefined') {

      if (obj.action == 'like_post') {

        var likes = "";

        if (typeof obj.likes != 'undefined') {
          likes =
            (parseInt(obj.likes) > 0) ?
            '<svg fill="#1877f2" width="22" height="22" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M21.216 8h-2.216v-1.75l1-3.095v-3.155h-5.246c-2.158 6.369-4.252 9.992-6.754 10v-1h-8v13h8v-1h2l2.507 2h8.461l3.032-2.926v-10.261l-2.784-1.813zm.784 11.225l-1.839 1.775h-6.954l-2.507-2h-2.7v-7c3.781 0 6.727-5.674 8.189-10h1.811v.791l-1 3.095v4.114h3.623l1.377.897v8.328z"/></svg>' :
            '<svg fill="#626a70cf" width="22" height="22" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M21.216 8h-2.216v-1.75l1-3.095v-3.155h-5.246c-2.158 6.369-4.252 9.992-6.754 10v-1h-8v13h8v-1h2l2.507 2h8.461l3.032-2.926v-10.261l-2.784-1.813zm.784 11.225l-1.839 1.775h-6.954l-2.507-2h-2.7v-7c3.781 0 6.727-5.674 8.189-10h1.811v.791l-1 3.095v4.114h3.623l1.377.897v8.328z"/></svg>';
          element.innerHTML = likes;
        }

        if (typeof obj.info != 'undefined') {
          var info_element = document.getElementById(obj.id);
          info_element.innerHTML = obj.info;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

function like_post(e) {

  e.preventDefault();
  var link = e.currentTarget.href;

  var data = {};
  data.link = link;
  data.action = "like_post";
  ajax_send(data, e.currentTarget);
}
```

```css
#icon_like {
  fill: #626a70cf;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#icon_like:hover {
  fill: #1877f2;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<a onclick="like_post(event)" href="<?=ROOT?>like/post/<?php echo $ROW['postid'] ?>" style="text-decoration:none;">
  <svg id="icon_like" width="22" height="22" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M21.216 8h-2.216v-1.75l1-3.095v-3.155h-5.246c-2.158 6.369-4.252 9.992-6.754 10v-1h-8v13h8v-1h2l2.507 2h8.461l3.032-2.926v-10.261l-2.784-1.813zm.784 11.225l-1.839 1.775h-6.954l-2.507-2h-2.7v-7c3.781 0 6.727-5.674 8.189-10h1.811v.791l-1 3.095v4.114h3.623l1.377.897v8.328z"/></svg>
</a>
```

This is the ajax for the like button.

```
    //read likes
        $likes = $post->get_likes($_GET['id'],$_GET['type']);

        //create info
        /////////////////
        $likes = array();
        $info = "";

                $i_liked = false;
                if(isset($_SESSION['mybook_userid'])){

                    $DB = new Database();

                    $sql = "select likes from likes where type='post' && contentid = '$_GET[id]' limit 1";
                    $result = $DB->read($sql);
                    if(is_array($result)){

                        $likes = json_decode($result[0]['likes'],true);

                        $user_ids = array_column($likes, "userid");

                        if(in_array($_SESSION['mybook_userid'], $user_ids)){
                            $i_liked = true;
                        }
                    }

                }

                $like_count = count($likes);

                if($like_count > 0){

                    $info .= "<br/>";

                    if($like_count == 1){

                        if($i_liked){
                            $info .= "<div style='text-align:left;'>You liked this post </div>";
                        }else{
                            $info .= "<div style='text-align:left;'> 1 person liked this post </div>";
                        }
                    }else{

                        if($i_liked){

                            $text = "others";
                            if($like_count - 1 == 1){
                                $text = "other";
                            }
                            $info .= "<div style='text-align:left;'> You and " . ($like_count - 1) . " $text liked this post </div>";
                        }else{
                            $info .= "<div style='text-align:left;'>" . $like_count . " others liked this post </div>";
                        }
                    }


                }

        /////////////////////////
        $obj = (object)[];
        $obj->likes = count($likes);
        $obj->action = "like_post";
        $obj->info = $info;
        $obj->id = "info_$_GET[id]";

        echo json_encode($obj);


    }
```

Comment: You'll need a way to indicate that it is already liked. E.g. `#icon_like:hover, #icon_like.liked { fill: #1877f2; }`

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Any debugging attempts so far?

Comment: Data will also be refreshed when the page is refreshed so you have to save data somewhere.

Comment: @evolutionxbox what would the JS function look like if I were to do that?

Comment: @NicoHaase I thought of using the addClass() removeClass() function in JS but am not sure how to implement it.

Comment: @BrijeshKalkani Do I need to create a new column in my database? I have a likes table with four columns: id, userid, contentid and likes

Comment: Please be warned: the given query is widely open for SQL injection and should never be used like this in production. Have a look at prepared statements!

Answer (score 0):

Added some comments to explain the solution as possible as I could;

1. We'll need to add a new CSS class for the liked state:

```css
#icon_like {
  fill: #626a70cf;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#icon_like:hover, #icon_like.liked {
  fill: #1877f2;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
```

2. In your returned `obj`, I assume you should have a boolean property called `isLiked` to indicate if the current user liked this post or not (If a post has likes, it doesn't mean that I liked it. Right?), so I assume you'll have it.
3. In your JS, just add that `liked` class to your like icon if the current user already liked this post based on the `isLiked` value:

```js
// Select the SVG icon
const likeIcon = document.getElementById('icon_like');

// Check if current user liked this post or not
if(obj.isLiked === true) {
  // In that case, we'll add the class we created to the SVG to make it blue
  likeIcon.classList.add('liked');
}

// If not, do nothing! (No need for else)
```

Hope you find this helpful in your situation!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't think I have a `isLiked` property in my returned `obj`. Can you have a look at my updated code and see how I can implement it?

Comment: @rustyrice23 Your current code check if the post has some likes or not. This logic isn't actually valid, as your post may have 3 likes but I am NOT one of those 3. If I re-used your code logic, the button will be blue and it shouldn't. Even localStorage won't be a valid solution in your case (We can store postId + isLiked but when user open from a different browser will find that the already liked post became gray again as localStorage gets reset!). Conclusion: The API should be our SSOT (single source of truth) and return that boolean `isLiked` for each post to do something on it.

Comment: If that's the case, do I need to write an entirely new code or do I add on to it?

Comment: @rustyrice23 You can add that new logic after you get the response, you don't need to re-write everything, just tweaking the current code.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I'm quite new to JS still so I'm not 100% confident in writing this code. Will you be able to guide me?

Comment: @rustyrice23 Absolutely! Just give me a full-working code (maybe share a Github repo) and deploy your Backend/API on any publicly accessible server so the API works on my machine as well, not just your localhost.

Comment: I'd love to do that but I'm having trouble with my database connection. My site works fine and is accessible on a public server, but when a user signs up, the data is not being saved into the database so the user can't actually log in. Maybe you could help me with that. Here's my Github repo: https://github.com/Rustyrice/rustyrice.github.io.git